# how to change the listview content only without changing list of items

Tags: android

I have a listview in which every listitem has one image and 4 textviews. I want to change only 2 textviews without changing the list and list of items.
Those textviews are changed every second. 
Is it possible in android?

Comment: use runonUIthread for those list. and keep updating the items

Comment: but it refresh the total listview I want to update only one textview

Answer (score 0):

You can update the text items of listView like this:

```
private void updateText(int index){
View v = ListView.getChildAt(index);

TextView updatedText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
updatedText .setText("changed Text");

}
```